# PyMongo delete document by type

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Cashbook Collection

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("1"), "DR" : "Bank", "CR" : "Roger", "Amount" : "100.00" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("2"), "DR" : "Bank", "CR" : "Amy", "Amount" : 999.99 }
```

```
...
CB = conn['Cashbook']

def CB_del_mult(search,value):
   query = {search:value}
   CB.delete.many(query)

CB.delete_many('Amount'," { $type : 'string' }")
```

According to the [MongoDO Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/), I can query by type.

I am attempting to remove all documents from Cashbook collection depending on whether 'Amount' is a string  value. In this example, the 1st entry will be completely removed as Amount is “100.00” (not 100.00)

The above code raises no errors, however is not deleting the string values.

Something like `CB.delete_many('Amount',{$type : 'string'} )` raises an invalid syntax error

Many thanks

Comment: some sample docs?

Answer (score 1):

JS and Python syntaxes are different and you need to use the correct one for the language you are working with.

Use pymongo documentation to find out the proper method signatures, options etc.  to use with pymongo. E.g. https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html for delete_many.

```
CB.delete_many({'Amount': {'$type': 'string'}})
```

Comment: Thanks. I am actually trying to move where Amount is a string. A SQL equivalent something like: DELETE FROM Cashbook WHERE Amount (is a string). Thanks

Comment: @ob318 You might be talking at crossed purposes. Can you edit your question to show a typical record you are wanting to delete.

Comment: I've tweaked the answer provided which may help you.